# django: mobile browser doesn't trigger download instead loads the file into browser

Tags: python, django

I have the following view. I test it through the laptop browsers and download takes place with no problem. But if I use browser of a document manager like 'Documents' on iphone, the very same requested file gets loaded into the browser. What am I missing here?

```
def servefiles(request, segmentID):
segments = []
obj = MainFile.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
file_name = MainFile.objects.get(file_id=segmentID).file_name
if request.method == 'GET':
    hosts = settings.HOSTS
    for i in hosts:
        try:
            url = 'http://' + i + ':8000/foo/' + str(segmentID)
            r = requests.get(url, timeout=1, stream=True)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                segments.append(r.content)
        except:
            continue
    instance = SeIDA('test', x=settings.M, y=settings.N)
    docfile = instance.decoder(segments)
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.write(docfile)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(file_name)
    return response
```

**Note**: If you might be wondering, SeIDA module encodes a data onto n segments such that presence of m segments is sufficed to recover the file. servefiles view retrieves the segments from storage backends and recovers the file and finally serves them. I have no trouble making requests on desktop browsers, but with no download manager on iphone have I been able to download the file.

Comment: Not entirely sure but you may need to set `content_type`... `HttpResponse(content_type='application/file_type_here')`

Comment: @Sayse makes perfect sense, because the downloaded file on the desktop browser opens up in browser too, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Sayse That was the way to go, add used mimetypes_guess_type() as argument to content_type keyword and that's it. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear! You may want to add your answer to your own question, it may help future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Sayse the trick was to specify the mimetypes in the content_type header

```
import mymetypes

response = HttpResponse(content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(file_name))
response.write(docfile)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(file_name)
return response
```